# How do I use NetBeans and SVN @version tag in the PhpDoc docblock?

Tags: php, svn, version-control, netbeans, phpdoc

I use NetBeans as my php ide and I have seen @version tags in the docblock that look like this:

```
@version $Id someinfo and timestamp
```

Does NetBeans have a way to automatically update this with each commit? Or am I missing the point entirely of this tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Well, no, Netbeans does not have a way.  But subversion does...

The exact tag is `$Id$`, and it corresponds to the svn property `svn:keywords=Id`.  Find the config file (On linux, it's usually under `~/.subversion/config`.  On windows I found it under `~\Application Data\Subversion\Config`.  Find that file (or create it if it doesn't exist) and then add these lines:

```
[miscellany]
enable-auto-props = yes

[auto-props]
*.php = svn:keywords=Id
```

If you want to set the End Of Line type to LF (`\n`), you can simply replace that last line with this:

```
*.php = svn:keywords=Id;svn:eol-style=LF
```

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

go to your source folder and execute this:

```
find . \( -name '.svn' -prune \) -o -name '*.php' -exec svn propset svn:keywords "Id " {} \;
```

this manually sets the keyword for each file